# Index out of range issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some items in one tableview shown like so...

[image]

If the `Add To Cart` button is clicked, then that particular data in cell is shown in another view like so..

[image]

But in the first tableview, if the last remove button (associated with the name `dddd`) is clicked, then it should be removed from the 2nd screen. But it crashes saying `index out of range` possibly because in the second screen the index of the name `dddd` is 1 and in the first screen its index is 2. This is the code of the remove action...

```
let context1 = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CartProducts")

            let sdf1 = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]
            let dfg2 = sdf1.name

            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", dfg2!)
            request.predicate = predicate
            request.fetchLimit = 1

            do{
                let count = try context1.count(for: request)
                if(count == 0){
                    // no matching object
                }
                else{
                    // at least one matching object exists

                    context1.delete(self.cartDetails[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
                    self.cartDetails.remove(at: indexPath.row) //crash occurs here
                    do {
                        try context1.save()
                    }
                }
            }catch let error as NSError { }
```

Comment: Remember to call `tableView.reloadData()` in parallel to updating datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You application crashes because you have two arrays `cartDetails` and `newProdDetails` and both has different indexes . now the case is there is no possibility that index of same object in different array is same.

i.e

`cartDetails` has  two items asd at 0 and ddd at 1

while
`newProdDetails` has three items  asd at 0, fgh at 1, ddd at 2

now think in `newProdDetails` in  `indexPath.row` of  `ddd` is 2 and if you search same index on  `cartDetails` which is not found --> CRASH

Suggestion:

First Fetch object like this with `productID` field not name field (add it if you don't have it in your entity)

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest< CartProducts> = CartProducts.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = Predicate.init(format: "itemID==\(productID)")

// withID you will get in your object of  `CartProducts`

if let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
    for object in result {
        context.delete(object) // Always a single object if found
    }
}

do {

    try context.save() // <- remember to put this :)
    // Here now you have to search `indexOf` of `ddd` to `cartDetails`  and delete it.
} catch { 
    // Do something... fatalerror
}
```

Here is example how to search index

```
if let index =   newProdDetails.index(where: { (object) -> Bool in
                return (object["productID"] as! Int) == 1

            }) {

 }
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: There's a doubt @Prashant Tukadiya. I can add an entity for `productID`. But how that `productID` be assigned values each time...?

Comment: @bvt is upto you. How you are filling data to array 1. is it from server then you will get product id from there.

Comment: I'm are not getting id from server.  An id for each product  was to be created from my end when each product is created. And it wasn't done  So thanks for pointing that out...:) Also does the 2nd code snippet u posted create such id's for each product...?

Comment: @bvt second code snippet i posted is helpful to search object by productID. and if you found index (observe if brackets) then just remove it from cartProducts

Comment: @bvt You need id from server. otherwise how server will know which product to purchase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164090/discussion-between-bvt-and-prashant-tukadiya).